# Understanding the Behavior of iwishrnd vs. 1/(wishrnd) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, statistics, distribution, matrix-inverse

I am testing out a Gibbs sampler to perform a Bayesian Hierarchical Regression and for one of my priors, I need to sample from a Inverse-Wishart distribution.  After having generated a sample covariance matrix, A, which is supposed to be positive definite and symmetric, I called `iwishrnd(A^-1, df)`.  Occasionally, I would get an error saying that the matrix must be positve-semidefinite and symmetric, however when I called `1/(wishrnd(A,df)`, I never encountered this error.  Since `iwishrnd(A^-1,df)` is supposed to be equivalent to `1/wishrnd(A,df)`, I was wondering if someone could tell me what was going on, i.e., something like MATLAB handles `1/(wishrnd(A,df)` better.  I mainly want to be able to trust the output and wanted to be sure that MATLAB is producing what I need.

I generated the sample covariance matrix following the methdology outlined by https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99153/sample-covariance-matrix.  The code I used is the following:

```
Q_T = eye(num_groups) - ones(num_groups,num_groups)./num_groups;
```

This generates the matrix Q_T

```
beta_init(:,ii) = regress(Y(groups(ii).index),X(groups(ii).index,:));
```

This generates an initial sample of betas for my Gibbs sampler.

```
S_o = ((Q_T*(beta_init)')'*(Q_T*(beta_init)'))./num_groups;
```

This would generate an initial sample covariance matrix.  The value of T is equal to the number of groups.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your actual code, including an example of how you create your "positive definite and symmetric" matrix `A`, so that others can replicate this. Is the error due to `iwishrnd` or `A^-1`? Why would you think that `iwishrnd(A^-1, df)` is equivalent to `wishrnd(A,df)`? They're different numerically. Have you looked at the code for either of these functions?

Comment: @horchler I'm not sure what causes the error, but I think they're equivalent because the MATLAB documentation states that if `W = wishrnd(Sigma,df)` then the inverse of `W` will have the Inverse-Wishart distribution with covariance matrix `Tau = inv(Sigma)` and with `df` degrees of freedom.  I made a typo in my initial question, which I corrected.  What's confusing is that if `A` wasn't invertible, then it would seem that calling `1/wishrnd(A,df)` should also fail along with `iwishrnd(A^-1,df)`.  That's why I was wondering if the code handled the covariance matrices differently somehow.